# Subset Intersection over $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, induction

Given the set $A\triangleq \{1,2,3,...,n\}$ prove that for any $n$ subsets of $A$ of size $k$, $(A_1,A_2,...,A_n)$, there exists $k$ subsets ordered as $(A_{j_1},A_{j_2},...,A_{j_k})$ such that for any $0<m\le k$, $|\cap_{i=1}^m A_{j_i}|\ge k-m+1$.

For example if $n=5$ and $k=2$, we're looking at 5 subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ where each subset is of size 2. The question here simply becomes if there exists 2 subsets with a non-zero intersection. Which is true since it cannot be that all subsets are distinct (since there are 5 of them to be picked).

Similarly if $n=5$ and $k=4$, it can be shown to be true since in this case, any $k$ subsets do the job.

By generalizing the above arguments, we have a proof for $k=2$ and $k=n-1$ for any given $n$ ($\ge2$). The question is if this can be shown for $2<k<n-1$. After working out with many other examples I believe this is true but a proof seems to elude me.

Comment: What does it mean "there exists 2 subsets with an intersection"? Do you mean "with a non-empty intersection"? 
Who is $m$ in $∩^m_{i=1}A_{j_i} ≥ k−m+1$?
What does it mean $∩^m_{i=1}A_{j_i} ≥ k−m+1$? Do you mean that the cardinality of $∩^m_{i=1}A_{j_i}$ is greater or equal to $k−m+1$?

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity, I've modified the original question. Indeed, I mean 2 subsets with a nonempty intersection. $m$ is just any number between $1$ and $k$ and given the ordering of the form $(A_{j_1},...,A_{j_k})$, we'd like to show it to be true for all $m$. Indeed, I refer to the cardinality of the intersection and want it to be $\ge$ k-m+1.